# error al representar un scatterplot con theme_ipsum

Tags: r, markdown, ggplot

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error, que no consigo resolver.

```
Error in make_ansi_style(x[["color"]]) : 
Unknown style specification: br_magenta
```

El código que ejecuto es un RMarkdown como el siguiente

```
{r, results='hide', warning=FALSE}

ggp_simple_1 <- ggplot(train, aes(x=price, y=train_simple_1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm , color="red", se=FALSE) +
  theme_ipsum()
```

Estoy cargando las librerías que muestro tal y como se indica en r-graph-gallery.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
```

El código siguiente en cambio no me da error:

```
ggp_simple_1 <- ggplot(train, aes(x=price, y=train_simple_1)) +
  geom_point() #+
  geom_smooth(method=lm , color="red", se=FALSE)
```

Entiendo que el problema es de la librería 'hbrthemes', pero no sé cómo puedo arreglarlo.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme que versión de `cli` tienes? Ejecuta esto: `packageVersion("cli")`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, es la ‘3.0.1’

Comment: No estoy seguro que funcione, pero prueba reiniciar completamente la sessión de R y sin cargar ninguna librería, actualiza este paquete mediante `install.packages("cli")`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, pues no, esa no es la solución. Estoy tratando de solucionarlo guardando las gráficas como imágenes y cargándolas a ver si así se soluciona.

Comment: El error que muestras es la inexistencia de cierto valor que se configura en el paquete `cli` , que me imagino puede venir por el lado de una versión antigua o de algún otro paquete que esta "redefiniendo" la funcionalidad que se espera de `cli`.  Ver: https://github.com/r-lib/cli/blob/1ca37531c98e4ffade2df8a55cfba9ce14feba51/R/ansi.R#L223

Comment: Por cierto este paquete que te menciono es funcionalidad para consola, no creo que tenga nada que ver directamente con la gráfica en sí ni con hbrthemes, tal vez algún mensaje por consola, prueba no usar el `geom_smooth` pero si el `theme_ipsum()`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, el ```geom_smooth``` lo necesito para representar la recta de regresión correspondiente a los puntos que grafico en el ```ggplot```

Comment: Si, no te estoy diciendo que no lo uses, solo que hagas la prueba de quitarlo para ver si el error sigue persistiendo.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, lo he probado y no hay error.

Comment: Bueno, eso confirma mi hipótesis, `geom_smooth()` cuando no indicas las formula, te  lo comenta por consola, y es ahí dónde entra a jugar el paquete `cli` con el que estás teniendo problemas. No es una solución, simplemente escondemos el problema, prueba evitar esto mediante `geom_smooth(method=lm , formula = y ~ x, color="red", se=FALSE)`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, funciona pero a medias. Si ejecuto el chunk manualmente, no da problemas. Antes a veces sí así que algo ha mejorado. Si ejecuto todo el rmarkdown completo para que cree un pdf, entonces obtengo un error ```Calls: <Anonymous> ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
Además: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Ejecución interrumpida```. Doy por cerrado este y abro uno nuevo con el nuevo problema. A veces ya me había salido este también.

Comment: Eso, parece otro error no relaciones con este.

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes se genera a partir de dos condiciones que se dan:

- Cuando usas `geom_smoot()` sin definir `formula` se usa `y ~ x` por defecto y al mismo tiempo se emite un mensaje estilizado en la consola, este mensaje se emite usando funcionalidad del paquete `cli`
- Tienes algún tipo de conflicto con el paquete antes mencionado, posiblemente una versión antigua o tal vez otro paquete que está redefiniendo el objeto `ansi_builtin_styles` (una [lista](https://github.com/r-lib/cli/blob/3e7f5d12f2d1cd5d9396e47fe6bff3acfed4a296/R/ansi.R#L48) dónde uno de los elementos justamente es `br_magenta`)

Una solución paliativa, pero el problema de fondo seguirá estando, es evitar que `geom_smooth()` muestre el mensaje en consola, para lo cual deberemos especificar la formula que debe usar esta función, por ejemplo:

```
geom_smooth(method=lm , formula = y ~ x, color="red", se=FALSE)
```